# detect mobile device and if mobile use alternative css style sheet?

Tags: php, css

hi can someone please help i am trying to find out a way of pointing the browser to an alternative css stylesheet if the user is accessing my site of a mobile device?

i have tried using the following code but it doesnt seem to be working for me. is there any other way of doing this maybe in javascript or some other way?

i would really appreciate it if someone could show me a way of doing this as everything i've treid doesnt work.

thanks

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
href="iPhone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Using "standard" device widths as your breakpoints aren't a very good idea:  http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/ and http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 0):

Try this (retrieved from [Perishable Press](http://perishablepress.com/the-5-minute-css-mobile-makeover/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.tld/screen.css" type="text/css" media="Screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.tld/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

The reason for having a line with `media="screen"` is to fix an issue with windows based mobiles that will take `media="screen"` over `media="handheld"`

Comment: nope am testing it on an iphone and this isnt working for me :/